# Java: value of parameter doesn't change

Tags: java

I just started with Java and to learn it I was trying to program a Tamagotchi in BlueJ. This is an extract of the code:

```
public class Tamagotchi
{
    private int hunger;
    private int mood;
    private int fatigue;
    private int hBorder;
    private int mBorder;
    private int fBorder;
    private String generalCondition;

    public Tamagotchi(int hungerBorder, int moodBorder, int fatigueBorder)
    {
        // Instanzvariable initialisieren
        hunger = 0;
        mood = 0;
        fatigue = 0;
        hBorder = hungerBorder;
        mBorder = moodBorder;
        fBorder = fatigueBorder;
        generalCondition = "indifferent";
    }

    public void setGeneralCondition(){
        if (fatigue > fBorder){
            generalCondition = "tired";
        }
            if ((fatigue < fBorder) & (hunger > hBorder)){
                generalCondition = "hungry";
            }
                if ((mood > mBorder) & (hunger < hBorder) &
                (fatigue < fBorder)){
                    generalCondition = "happy";
                }
        else {
            generalCondition = "indifferent";
        }
    }

    public void play()
    {
        if (hunger > hBorder){hunger += 2; mood += 2; fatigue += 3;
        }
        else {}
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

    public void eat(){
        if (fatigue > fBorder){hunger -= 2; fatigue += 2;
        }
        else{}
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

   public void sleep(){
        if (hunger > hBorder){hunger += 1; mood -= 1; fatigue = 0;
        }
        else{hunger += 1; mood += 1; fatigue = 0;
        }
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

    public void pet(){
        hunger += 1;
        mood += 2;
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

    public String getGentralCondition(){
        return generalCondition;
    }

    public void makeHappy(){
        eat();
        sleep();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `generalCondition` does not change when I use any of the methods. I think something with the method `setGeneralCondition` is wrong but I don't know where the problem is. Can somebody help :/ ?

THX in advance.
EDIT:
I posted the hole code now. As I said in the comment: I want the `generalCondition` to change whenever I use a method like eat(), play()...
The method `setGeneralCondition` was supposed to check if one of the values hunger mood or fatigue passes a certain border and change the Condition (to tired, hungry or happy). But whenever I use one of the other methods the `generalCondition` doesn't change.

Comment: Your code is missing implementation of `eat()` and `sleep()` methods. What else is wrong?

Comment: `hungerBorder = hungerBorder` — This causes trouble. What do you think will be the effect of this statement?

Comment: Furthermore, you are comparing `String`s with `==` or `!=`. **Never** do that.

Comment: I assume you call the method setGeneralCondition inside of eat or sleep (or call play there)? If so, we need to see those implementations in order to help.

Comment: 1. this is an extract so ignore the makeHappy method. 2. when I use e.g. play() the values of hunger, mood and fatigue change. after these were increased (or decreased) the setGeneralCondition methods should check whether one of the value is above a certain border and change the generalCondition to a string value when it is above that border. When the fatigue value is above e.g. 2 the Condition should change to "tired". The problem is that whenever I use e.g. play() the generalCondition stays at its inititial value ("indifferent")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I have made further edits to your code and have come up with a little main that runs your code and changes generalCondition! Check it out and run it for yourself to see.

My intuition tells me this class Tamagotchi is a class file or an object Tamagotchi that will be used by a main method that rests somewhere in another file.  If that is the case, I believe it is a simple fix and all you need to do is add `this.` in a lot of places.  I have gone ahead and done just that for you below.  Try this and let me know if this works!

```java
public class Tamagotchi{
    private int hunger;
    private int mood;
    private int fatigue;
    private int hungerBorder;
    private int moodBorder;
    private int fatigueBorder;
    private String generalCondition;

    public Tamagotchi(int hungerBorder, int moodBorder, int fatigueBorder)
    {
        // Instanzvariable initialisieren
        this.hunger = 30;
        this.mood = 30;
        this.fatigue = 30;
        this.hungerBorder = hungerBorder;
        this.moodBorder = moodBorder;
        this.fatigueBorder = fatigueBorder;
        this.generalCondition = "indifferent";
    }

    public void setGeneralCondition(){
        if (fatigue > fatigueBorder){
            this.generalCondition = "tired";
            return;
        }
        if ((fatigue < fatigueBorder) && (hunger > hungerBorder)){
            this.generalCondition = "hungry";
            return;
        }
        if ((mood > moodBorder) && (hunger < hungerBorder) && (fatigue < fatigueBorder)){
            this.generalCondition = "happy";
            return;
        } else {
            this.generalCondition = "indifferent";
        }
    }

    public String getGeneralCondition(){
        return generalCondition;
    }

    public void play()
    {
        if (!generalCondition.equalsIgnoreCase("hungry")){
            hunger += 2; mood += 2; fatigue += 3;
        } else {
        }
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

    public void eat(){
        if (fatigue > fatigueBorder){
            hunger -= 2; fatigue += 2;
        } else{
        }
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

    public void sleep(){
        if (hunger > hungerBorder){
            hunger += 1; mood -= 1; fatigue = 0;
        } else{
            hunger += 1; mood += 1; fatigue = 0;
        }
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

    public void pet(){
        hunger += 1;
        mood += 2;
        setGeneralCondition();
    }

    public void makeHappy(){
        eat();
        sleep();
    }
}
```

Here is a little main method I wrote to test the code above.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tamagotchi test = new Tamagotchi(10, 10, 10);
        test.play();
        test.makeHappy();

        System.out.println(test.getGeneralCondition());
    }
}
```

Output :

```
hungry
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. here is a link to basic coding styles.  Practice coding with these styles as it makes your code easier to read for others, yourself, it looks a lot cleaner, and it is easier to see and fix errors! [Coding Style Guide](https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md)

Answer (score 0):

There are few major problems with the code that you posted.

As sloughy stated, you need to add "this" to hungerBorder, moodBorder, and fatigueBorder in the Tamagotchi constructor. What you are currently doing is setting the PARAMETERS hungerBorder, moodBorder and fatigueBorder to themselves. When you add "this" in front of a variable, you are now referencing the class variable regardless of whatever local variables you are currently working with.

Additionally, you shouldn't compare Strings with == and !=. This will only work when both strings in the comparison are pointing to the same internal reference. Instead you should use .equals() which can be called like this:

```
String testString = "test";
String otherString = "other";
if (testString.equals(otherString)) {
    System.out.println("equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("not equal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working code from compilation perspective. The problem you've met is probably in data or logic you implemented. To get `generalCondition` changed you need condition
`((mood > mBorder) & (hunger < hBorder) & (fatigue < fBorder))` to return `true` otherwise you'll set same default value.

Few tips:

1. Most probably you didn't debug your app. Start doing this especially when you new in programming/java.
2. Use `&&` instead of `&` short. In 99% of usage this in `if` clause it's better (with time you'll know why)